# Combine applyDayNight() with custom theme overlay?

Tags: android, androidx, theme-daynight

In `androidx` you can easily toggle between day/night mode. E.g.:

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
   <!-- attributes -->
</style>
```

And when toggling theme:

```java
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(nightMode);
getDelegate().applyDayNight();
```

Now, let's say I want to add a minor customization to either the day or the night theme:

```xml
<style name="LimeTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/lime1</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/lime2</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/lime3</item>
</style>
```

How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

May be you need a folder —— [values-night].

In your theme.xml(or style.xml), you can set the day theme like :

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme"  parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar" >
    <item name="minor customization">@style/ThemeOverlay.MyTheme.DayCustom</item>
</style>
```

In your theme-night.xml(or style-night.xml):

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme"  parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar" >
    <item name="minor customization">@style/ThemeOverlay.MyTheme.NightCustom</item>
</style>
```

And in style,you shoule init these:

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.MyTheme.NightCustom" parent="">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/nightLime1</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/nightLime2</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/nightLime3</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.MyTheme.DayCustom" parent="">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/dayLime1</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/dayLime2</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/dayLime3</item>
</style>
```

> The key is in **ThemeOverlay**, the parent of   ThemeOverlay.MyTheme.DayCustom or ThemeOverlay.MyTheme.NightCustom,is "",because the system will automatic recognition it is ThemeOverlay, and just change the style you set,like colorPrimary,colorPrimaryDark...

Comment: And how do you make `getDelegate().applyDayNight()` account for this theme overlay?

Comment: System will auto account for it.Because you set `<item name="minor customization">@style/ThemeOverlay.MyTheme.NightCustom</item>` in **theme-night.xml(or style-night.xml)**

Comment: I need day/night theme plus an *optional* overlay. E.g. Light, Dark, Super-dark. How do I make it optional given a boolean setting in `SharedPreferences`?

Comment: just use `setTheme(**)` in your related Activity？

Comment: Ok, so you are suggesting that one should opt-out from the automatic day/night stuff and simply apply a full style? Certainly that would work, but it will be slower. The existing day/night theming through `applyDayNight()` is incredibly fast. I was looking for a way to inject some custom styling into this "fast method" that Google is using.